# How to open the print queue window in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, printing, window, queue

Does anyone know of a simple way to open a print queue window in vb.net?

[image]

Comment: did you able to get make it work? i also need this same help....!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
Dim myPrinter As New Process()
myPrinter.StartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo("\\printerServer\PrinterName", "")
myPrinter.Start()
```

Comment: I am using a network printer so where do I get the printerServer part?  We are on the right track!   Thank you.

Comment: Yeah so if it is a network printer then you just need to verify which server the print is hosted on. Just go to Devices and Printers on a workstation and it should say something like **OfficePrinter on OfficeServer01**

Print Server or something. Where ever it is hosted to be networked out of.

Comment: I apologize i stand corrected. The printer is accessed via IP address.  I ended up accomplishing this step by using the command prompt like this:

Comment: @ZachSchulze, sir, how can i open on local server? (local computer/printer)?

Answer (score 0):

Dim OpenCMD
        OpenCMD = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
        OpenCMD.run("rundll32.exe printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /o /n ""Printer Name""")